# which value would SAS assign to the variable?

Tags: sas

Given the SAS data set WORK.ONE:

```
Obs       Revenue2008   Revenue2009   Revenue2010
---       -----------   -----------   -----------
1                 1.2           1.6           2.0
```

The following is the SAS program submitted.

```
data WORK.TWO;
     set WORK.ONE; 
     Total=mean(of Rev:);
  run;
```

What value will SAS assign to Total?

For my understand, it should cause an error, because Rev is not defined yet. But somehow this is not right. Could anyone tell me why? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `of Rev:` in the `mean()` function says that it should take the mean of all variables that start with "Rev", so since the values of the variables that start with "Rev" are 1.2, 1.6, and 2.0, the value of total will be 1.6.